# How can I make my columns show one after the other with CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a `<div>` that contains many columns, one after the other.  In each column I'm showing an image.  I've set my design so that only 6 columns are shown per row using `row-col-X`. Once I reach 6 images in one row, the other images show in the next row as expected. However, they show unorganized, and I need them to show as I explain in the following images (it's easier to explain with images):

This is what I need:
[image]

This is what's happening:
[image]

Here's my code (I'm using Bootstrap 4)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-cols-lg-7 row-cols-md-7 row-cols-sm-7 row-cols-7">
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
  <a href="#" class="col"><img src="images/card.svg" alt="Card"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The described behavior isn't reproducible https://codeply.com/p/zc5qqA8ugU

Comment: if you add those images path that will be easy to see it, though try img: 100%

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using what @zim proposed on codeply (http://codeply.com/p/zc5qqA8ugU).
I wrapped everything in a `container` and that solved it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-lg-7 row-cols-md-7 row-cols-sm-6 row-cols-6">
        <a href="#" class="col"><img src="//placehold.it/50x20" alt="Card"></a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a display tag with the value set to inline in the CSS window under the class name:

```
display:inline
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another `class="name"` to div tag & apply this property:

```
{ 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
}
```

The flexible items are displayed horizontally >> as a row